# Are there any advanced apps that are built using fabric js?

Tags: performance, html, fabricjs

I got lots of simple apps or examples that are built using Fabric.js.

Can I use Fabric.js for making advanced applications? I want to check some apps and see it's performance so that I would confirm that Fabric.js can handle big apps too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We built Fabric specifically to power [design editor](http://printio.ru/tees/new) on Printio.ru. It's used by 1000+ visitors daily.

From other big sites there's [easel.ly](http://easel.ly) — visual themes creation tool. Also [mywallsticker.de](http://www.my-wallsticker.de/index.php?cl=designer&html5=1&text=fabricjs), [scrollkit.com](https://www.scrollkit.com/), and [others](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Who%27s-using-Fabric).

Comment: How does the image filters in `printio.ru` work? Does it work using the same `API functions` provided by `fabric.js` Ex: The `transparency` and other image filters are blazing fast in that website . When I apply two or three image filters in my app, it takes a lot of time to render.Any ideas on how to optimize?

Comment: Yep, just standard filters. Depends on the size of the image and all the other things happening on the main thread (which could be taking away from the computation power).

Comment: yeah..thanx the image I used was around 1400x2400 px image, so I reduced size and it worked awesome, but still when any convolute filters are applied like blur or sharpen, then for any other filter if applied takes time to render, any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Hi..I tried out but in vain, even in the image-filters example provided in the `fabric.js.com`, if you apply blur filter, and the try out applying other filters, it renders slow, please check this http://fabricjs.com/image-filters.

Comment: Hey, I just saw this thread,https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2442, yeah it seems to be slow in chrome, but in firefox it works cool

Comment: How can you achive the 3D is there any method available in fabric.js

Answer (score 2):

Large sites that using FabricJS are listed here https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Who%27s-using-Fabric

Answer (score 1):

http://printio.ru/ is the one of best one, what kind of advance apps you are looking for ?
check out the discussion on google groups
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fabricjs
you will get some idea